# Please delete the misspelled [pronounciation] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I have accidentally misspelled [pronunciation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronunciation) and thus created a meaningless [pronounciation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pronounciation) tag. I do not know how to (and probably do not have the privileges to) delete it.

Apologies to the moderators for increasing their load. :-(

Comment: Provided nobody else accidentally puts it on their question, and you have fixed it on your question, the tag-roomba will come by after a little while and take care of it automagically

Comment: @Shalvenay: Phew. Thanks!

Comment: Also rest assured that tags are easy to directly rename with mod tools, in case one ever goes a while before being caught.